# Conservative second order interpolation from Lagrangian grid to Eulerian grid

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, interpolation, hyperbolic-equations

I was solving an advection equation of the following form;
$$\partial_{t}f+\partial_{x}(v(x)f)=0$$
with a Lagrangian where grid is advected instead of the distribution function $f$ with velocity $v(x)$ in the following way;
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=v(x).$$
Now I need to interpolate the distribution function from the Lagrangian advected grid to the initial grid such that the total area under the curve ($\mathcal{N}$) stays conserved,
$$\int_{x_{min}}^{x_{max}}f\,dx=\mathcal{N}$$
I tried with naive Piece-wise Linear approach with boundary being set to 0 and found that the integration does not stay conserved.
The boundary setting to 0 prescription is arbitrary as I do not have a distribution function value beyond boundary and in Lagrangian scheme boundary condition is not required.
Any help regarding a numerical interpolation routine which can make the integration conserved would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful here. A conservation law (as the one you consider) states that the temporal change of the quantity $f$

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{x_\min}^{x_\max} f(t, x) dx $$

is determined according to the fluxes at the boundary:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{x_\min}^{x_\max} f(t, x) dx + v(x_\max) f(t, x_\max) - v(x_\min) f(t, x_\min)= 0.$$
In other words, the substance is not disappearing or being generated within your domain for some other reason.

However, for general $v(x), f(t, x_\max), f(t, x_\min)$ you cannot expect that

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{x_\min}^{x_\max} f(t, x) dx = 0.$$
(This is in fact what you are asking, just differentiated with respect to time).

This is intuitively clear if you consider e.g. a [pipe-flow](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/nedlagte-emner/INF2340/v05/foiler/sim05.pdf) when there is a higher outflow velocity than inflow velocity: The amount of substance cannot stay the same over time.

To test your implementation, you might want to consider periodic conditions: $v(x_\min) = v(x_\max), f(t, x_\min) = f(t, x_\max)$. In that case, you should have that the integral of $f$ is indeed constant.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but for any general case this is true form Leibniz integral rule, however your $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ should change with time which is the case for me.

Comment: Further in I like to interpolate the function which is on the evolving grid $x\in [x_{min}(t),x_{max}(t)]$ to the initial static grid $x\in [x_{min}(0),x_{max}(0)]$ such that the area under the curve stays conserved. I understand that demanding the conservation of the integral could lead to pile up at the boundary but that is not the issue for my case.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Did you take a look at [Reynolds Transport Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem) ?